# How can I create a learnable parameter or weight vector whose values are either 1 or -1

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I need to build a neural network which is known as learnable parameter or a weight vector. In that way, only one vector will be generated and multiplied with the data. I have created that as following:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class LearnableMultiplier(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LearnableMultiplier, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                      initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                      trainable=True)

        super(LearnableMultiplier, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return inputs * self.kernel

inputs = Input(shape=(64,))
multiplier = LearnableMultiplier()(inputs)  
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=multiplier )
```

I need the vector learnable parameter defined above to be selected from values of either 1 or -1. I mean each value of that vector which is multiplied with my data can only be 1 or -1. Is that feasible? How can I do it?

Comment: Neural Nets are trained with backprop so the values must be continous, so 1 and -1 with nothing in the middle should be impossible

Comment: @Caridorc OK, what's about if I want each value of the learnable parameters any value different of zero?

Comment: It depends how you define different from zero, is 0.0000001 different from zero?

Comment: No, for example, I consider 0.1  different from zeros @Caridorc

Comment: You can try using a function that given an input from 0 to 1 will give out an output close to 1 or -1

Comment: @Caridorc That is what I am asking about. But, how can I do that? That should be implemented for the learnable parameter, right? so how can I do it?